# Issue with Context (Android ADT)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adt, android-context

I'm trying to create a shared preferences to save `TextFields` in my app. Whenever I try to use context it will not allow me to call `getApplicationContext()` it gives me the error (`"No method Defined for this class"`). Whenever I create a `Context` defined as `null` it gives me a time error.

My code is:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you executing this code? If in an Activity you can use `this` wherever you need to pass a `Context` as `Activity` extends `Context`.

Comment: In that case use `getActivity` to get a reference to the current `Context`